# Facebook {page-id}/tabs not working with v2 sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have a web app that also integrates facebook login.
Since v1 is available only until 30th april 2015, I've changed the JS calls to use v2 sdk (sdk.js) but the {page-id}/tabs request no longer works.

Facebook responds with an error:

code: 200

message: "(#200) Requires either an app access token, or a page access token for this Page"

type: "OAuthException"

This is the api call:

```
checkForInstalledApp: function(pageId, callbackFunction){
    FB.api(pageId+'/tabs/'+appid, function(response){
        if (response && !response.error) {
            callbackFunction(response.data.length > 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Changing back to all.js works just fine. Also the login is successful. Only {page-id}/tabs returns an error.. so far.

Anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you have to use a Page Token even for reading the tabs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/tabs#read

I suggest trying it with a Page Token.

If you don´t know how to generate Page Tokens, the following links will help you:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

Even if in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/page/tabs - Reading section - they specify that "A page access token is required to retrieve tabs for a Page" and we have the same thing mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/tabs, if we check the changelog we see that "The tabs edge on the Page node now requires a Page token for GETs". So this is actually something v2 specific and it shouldn't appear in the v1 docs.

The tabs api call works if used like this: page.id+'/tabs?access_token='+page.access_token